# JavaScript não cria cookie

Tags: javascript

```js
function createCookie(name, value, days)
{
     var expires;
     if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
     }
     else {
        expires = "";
     }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
 }
   createCookie('arquivo','teste','1');
   
   function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}

alert( getCookie('arquivo'));
```

Comment: Se estiver a testar localmente tenha atenção pois alguns browser, como o chrome desabilitam os cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta desabilitar essa opção no seu Chrome.

Settings > Privacy > Content Settings e deixa a configuração igual essa imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]